# google adslot syntax - is there a way to not specify a criteria?

Tags: adsense, interstitial

I am trying to introduce interstitial adverts for a web project but I am confused about how to use an existing adslot without defining a criteria for that (or if it is even possible?)

From the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference
https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/key-value-targeting

There are some examples that show a chosen category of advert to be shown, for example:

googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/sports', [728, 90], 'div-1');

or

googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris',
googletag.enums.OutOfPageFormat.INTERSTITIAL);

when I try to use the sample code with my account ID and the ad-unit name, it does not work. I don't want to define cateogries at this stage, I would prefer that it is done automatically.

For example

```
    interstitialSlot = googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/26*****997/auto',
    googletag.enums.OutOfPageFormat.INTERSTITIAL);
```

or

```
    interstitialSlot = googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/26*****997/interstitial-unit-name',
    googletag.enums.OutOfPageFormat.INTERSTITIAL);
```

but neither of these formats are accepted and the documentation seems to be somewhat lacking in other examples.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
interstitialSlot = googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/26*****997/auto',
```

googletag.enums.OutOfPageFormat.INTERSTITIAL);

Use this and wait 24 hours only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).